# IAM: How to structure Policies and Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm new to AWS. Our team uses several products (Amplify, S3, DynamoDB, Lambdas, CloudWatch, Cognito and more to come).

**I don't get how I should structure the permissions given to my "developers" group.**

I tried link to the group one managed policy per product - but there is a low limit of 10 policies per group which doesn't allow me to give permissions on all of the products we use.

Then I tried to create a big policy for our developers, with all the products. But it exceeded the 6,444 characters limit of a JSON policy.

I'm lost, can someone tell me **which logic I should apply when giving AWS permissions to my users** without hitting a limit at some point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can whitelist an entire service via the `*` symbol, for example to whitelist S3 the permissions would look like the below

```
{
      "Sid": "AllowS3",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
}
```

Generally if you have a large number of permissions for allow with few for deny I would suggest at looking at whether you can have in your policy a statement for allowing all services, with a smaller statement for deny access to the individual permissions of those statements. Below is an example.

```
{
      "Sid": "AllowS3",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
},
{
      "Sid": "DenyS3Delete",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:Delete*",
      "Resource": "*"
}
```

Ensure you don't add any deny for services that are not allowed. The [ordering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow) for IAM permissions are as follows:

- Explicit deny - Is there a deny statement for using the service call. If so deny
- Explicit allow - There's an allow for the service, so allow
- Implicit deny - If no permissions set then the service is denied by default

Make use of AWS managed policies where possible (such as PowerUser) to set a base set of permissions that are managed by Amazon

Comment: Hey, thanks. Infrastructure people always told me "Deny all, allow by exception". Is it a good way of thinking on real life AWS? Is it managable to give to devs only the permissions they need on the ARN they need?

Comment: Whats probably being referred to is least privilege access, basically people should only have the permissions they need to do their job. Start with locking down services, if it comes down to specific resources add these once you have some base permissions. Remember the solution must be manageable, for whomever is responsible for maintaining the IAM policies. Take a read of https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS-Security-Pillar.pdf for more best practices with IAM :)